# Will filtering be allowed for triage?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage

Just noticed that the new "Triage" review queue lacks filtering. Will it be allowed?

Comment: It's been 6 months since this question was asked... But not even a comment or answer???

Comment: @Code one deleted answer :)

Comment: don't mind me and my late +1, I am just a passerby rolling *anastatica hierochuntica*....

Comment: This question will be better addressed on meta.SO, as that is currently the only site with a Triage review queue. They are pretty quick to comment and answer stuff like this, too, so hopefully your request will receive more attention that it has here.