# Favourite Tag Review in Triage

Tags: feature-request, review, triage

Today I am reviewing Triage questions and I skipped almost all except not formatted questions! because of no expertise of the domain.

My Query is :

- Is it possible to get the review questions only based on the favourite tag first?
- There can be an option when the Favourite tag question has been asked and the notification should be pushed to the reviewer!

Just asking :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244855.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will filtering be allowed for triage?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244855/will-filtering-be-allowed-for-triage)